# Is it possible to use a UIBarButtonSystemItem in a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

UISegmentedControl allows me to make individual segments have text or images.  I'd like to use a system icon (that is appropriate for what I'm trying to do), but I don't see how to grab the UIImage out of the UIBarButtonSystemItem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You'll need to provide your own artwork.